# Android Slide animation on single fragment after swipe

Tags: android, json, animation, android-fragments, slide

I have a JSONArray with several keys (size of array is always different). I'm working with this JSON array in one fragment with bind events on swipe left/right. After swipe left are taken values under key **[actual_array_posistion - 1]** and same for swipe right **[actual_array_posistion + 1]**. I'm displaying fetched values from JSON array under given key into predefined textviews in fragment layout.

- Problem is that, there is no slide animation on the fragment.

Any simple and efficient idea, how to solve this problem? I thought that i create fragments dynamically like on this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). But i think that the solution in the link is not applicable in this case.

Thanks for any advice or simple example.

Comment: what do you mean:  "there is no slide animation on the fragment"?

Comment: If i'm swiping textviews are filled by new fetched values from JSON. But in case that user is swiping expects slide animation. 
Question is, how can i add slide animation or something similar on single fragment.

Comment: start an animation on the Fragment.getView() view or I'm missing something?

Comment: Could you provide some example please?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello atully i am not totally get what you looking for but if you want load animation from json to native android so Airnub provide **Lottie library**
just use it and may be there was problem in json so i will also upload their tutorial link

[Make animation](https://medium.com/mobiddiction/native-app-animations-in-xcode-using-sketch-after-effects-and-lottie-from-airbnb-8fb68b7661d1)

hear is link by which you can know how to use library in android

[lottie library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)